# Get content of 2 classes within 1 class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML like

```
<a href="/blabla" class="matchupLink">
    <span class="teams"> USA</span>
    <span class="teams">Brazil</span>
</a>
```

I want to get the HTML of the elements with class 'teams' within class 'matchupLink'

I tried

```
$('.matchupLink').each(function (index, obj) {
  var teams = $(this).find('.teams');
  console.log(teams.html())
});
```

But that only returns the first instance of the `.teams` class within each `.matchupLink` class. So here it only returns USA and not Brazil.

I want to calculate how many characters both `teams` class have within each `matchupLink` class. Because then if characterCount >=20, I want to display ellipses.

What should I be doing?

Thanks

Comment: How many characters each, or all together?

Comment: Because then if characterCount >=20, I want to display ellipses.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine selectors with the classes

```
$('.matchupLink .teams')
```

This will return you an array of objects with the class "teams".

**UPDATE**

[Here's a fiddle that prints to the console the length](http://jsfiddle.net/55L4C/)

```
$('.matchupLink .teams').each(function(index, item){
    var $item = $(item);
    var teamNameLength = $item.html().length;
    console.log($item.html() + ' length is: ' + $item.html().length);
    // if ($item.html().length >= 20){
    //     ::do logic for ellipses::
    // }
});
```

**note the USA prints out a value of 4 because you have a space before in your example.

**UPDATE 2**

[Fiddle alerting the length of both teams](http://jsfiddle.net/55L4C/1/)

To get the length of both teams, create a variable outside of the loop and increment it appropriately.

```
var lengthOfBothTeams = 0;

$('.matchupLink .teams').each(function(index, item){
    lengthOfBothTeams += $(item).html().length;
});   

alert('Length of both team names is: ' + lengthOfBothTeams);
```

Comment: Hi, what should I do if I want to calculate how many characters both `teams` class have within each `matchupLink` class.

Comment: @DanyP - I just updated my answer.  That should do the trick for you.  Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. The challenge I'm having is that, the length >=20 must combine both .teams class together (that are within the matchupLink class). So for example USA + Brazil would be (in this case) 10, so the logic >=20 wouldnt apply for the ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` will work on the first match in the set in your example

you should loop over the teams and not the matches

```
$('.matchupLink .teams').each(function () {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`html()` only returns the HTML content of the first matched element in the jQuery object. Use `each()` to iterate over the element and display their HTML content.

```
$('.matchupLink .teams').each(function (index, obj) {
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```